# Use user_passes_test after login_required in function based view

Tags: django

I have written a passing condition for user which is as follows:

```
def check_admin(user):
    isAdmin = False
    if user.role == "ADMIN":
        isAdmin=True
    return isAdmin
```

This is working fine in class based view:

```
class AgentUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url='/agents'

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(check_admin))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AgentUpdate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Bu when i use it in function based view it is giving me error `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'role'`

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(check_admin)
def upload_topic(request):
    ---- Rest of the view---
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if the user is authenticate or not

```
def check_admin(user):
    if not user.is_active:
       return False;
    isAdmin = False
    if user.role == "ADMIN":
        isAdmin=True
    return isAdmin
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/

Comment: +1. It worked but shouldn't it work like ```login_required``` decorator will take care of the ```AnonymousUser``` ? As i have applied it before user_passes_test so it should handle this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Your test method should exclude when the user is anonymous (Not logged in)

```py
def check_admin(user):
    return not user.is_anonymous and user.role == "ADMIN"
```